# How do I call a function in truffle console by specifying function parameters, value, to, from and gas values?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

Solidity function:

```
function abc(address x, address y, address z) external payable returns (uint256 x) {
    // something
}
```

In web3.py (python), I have called it successfully after deploying using following code:

```
w3.eth.call({
    'value':1*10**18,
    'gas':200000,
    'gasPrice':25*10**9,
    'to':contract_address,
    'from':myaddress,
    'data':data
})
```

`data` is created by combining the addresses appropriately.

I tried the following in truffle:

```
ex = await Example.deployed()
ex.abc('0x...', '0x...', '0x...').call({'from':'0x...', 'to':'0x...', 'value':1*10**18,'gas':200000, 'gasPrice':20})
```

I'm getting error: `Uncaught TypeError: ex.abc(...).call is not a function`

But when I run `ex.abc`, I get below output:

```
[Function (anonymous)] {
  call: [Function (anonymous)],
  sendTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
  estimateGas: [Function (anonymous)],
  request: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

So, how do I call this function in truffle?

Answer (score 0):

`ex.abc().call()` requires `ex.abc()` to return a function which isn't the case. It should be `ex.abc.call(parameters, {'from':...})`.

Working code:

```
ex.abc.call('0x...', '0x...', '0x...', {'from':'0x...', 'to':'0x...', 'value':1*10**18,'gas':200000, 'gasPrice':20})
```